# Code executing all lines despite only required to excute a part of code

Tags: python

So it goes like this, When I enter a query it is parsed and two values and pulled out this is the date and indicator and gets the appropriate response to for that date initially

```
response = {'l_result': [{'deaths': 5, 'tested': 5,}]}

if value('DATE'):
     print("===================")
     print("this is the response ")
     print(response)
     print("===================")

if value('indicator'):
mapped_indicator = values('indicator')[-1]
   if mapped_indicator == 'Tested':
      tested_list = [
       {'total_tested': response.get('tested'),
        'new_tests': response.get('new_tests')}]
          print(tested_list)
```

My problem is that all the code runs.
I want that if only a date is found then all information in response will be shown and if a date and indicator are found then only specific information for the indicator is shown.

my output is

```
===================
this is the response
{'l_result': [{'deaths': 5, 'tested': 5,}]}
===================

tested: 5
```

as you see the result for the entire code is there and what I wanted was just

```
tested: 5
```

Can you tell me how to do this

Comment: What is `value`? You never seem to test anything in `response`.

Comment: Please add more grammar and punctuation to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just gave you a simple example, hope this helps in your case, this is not with a dictionary structure

```
date = '10/19/2020'
indicator = 'Y'

if  indicator =='Y' and date == '10/19/2020':
    print('Indicator is ',indicator)
elif date == '10/19/2020':
    print('Only date has a value')


print('2nd case when indicator is empty')

date = '10/19/2020'
indicator = None

if  indicator =='Y' and date == '10/19/2020':
    print('Indicator is ',indicator)
elif date == '10/19/2020':
    print('Only date has a value')
```

Answer (score 0):

from what information  you have provided, it looks like you have to use the logical operation "and" and then have a seperate for

if value('DATE'): and value('indicator')

elif.....

Comment: So are you saying that I will have to do             
 if value('DATE')

elif  if value('DATE'): and value('indicator')